# Why so many errors are displaying as "ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block"

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

Production database has restarted unfortunately. When I gone through the logs, I have observed below error several times(More than 1,00,000 times).

"ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block"

How to avoid the above error?

Comment: Well, it depends what you are doing.  If running a script using `psql`, then use the `ON_ERROR_STOP` parameter.  Furthermore, find the first error message that causes all the others failing.

Comment: Please guide me how to implement the ON_ERROR_STOP.

Comment: Have you tried to google it?